# Getting java.policy.applet working outside of eclipse

Tags: java, policy

This should be a relatively simple fix, but I cannot find how to get it working. I've created a java applet and it works great while running it in eclipse, unfortunately I can't get it working outside of eclipse. Here is the important part of the error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission background.jpg read)
```

Which I've figured out seems to have to do with the policy stuff, but I don't understand it well enough to get it working, I guess. If I put the html file with applet tag inside the eclipse bin folder then it works beautifully, but if I copy everything in that folder (including the java.policy.applet file) to another folder, it gives the above error.

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, please help! If I can just tell the program where that file is because it seems to be ignoring it entirely. This is the policy file and was automatically generated by eclipse:

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Apr 16 17:20:59 EDT 2002*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: Can you post piece of code, where you're doing file operations (opening image file)?

Comment: this `background.jpg` is in compiled the Java package ???

Answer (score 1):

To specify the location of the policy file, use:

`appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=file:///path/to/policy/file HTMLfile`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem developing an applet for Belgian Electronic Identity card. The solution for me was to create a self-signed JAR. I'm investigating on how to do this directly in Eclipse. 
Ensure your jdk is in your path (so that you can access following tools) and then :

- keytool -genkey -keystore yourKeyStoreFile -alias toto
- keytool -selfcert -keystore yourKeyStoreFile -alias toto

Those two commands create the keys and self-signed certificate, and only need to be executed once. Then, to actually sign the jar, use :

- jarsigner -keystore yourKeyStore jarfile.jar toto

Hope this will help...